# Slack API only picking up text field

Tags: java, websocket, slack-api

I'm trying to send a message with attachments to a slack chat, using a slack bot. The connections to the api is done via WebSocket, and until now, everything works fine, everything but sending a message with attachments.

Here is the code snippet that sends the message:

```
public final void replyInteractive(WebSocketSession session, Event event, InteractiveMessage reply) {
    try {
        reply.setText(encode(reply.getText()));
        reply.setType(EventType.MESSAGE.name().toLowerCase());
        if (reply.getChannel() == null && event.getChannelId() != null) {
            reply.setChannel(event.getChannelId());
        }
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(reply.toJSONString()));
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {  // For debugging purpose only
            logger.debug("Reply (Message): {}", reply.toJSONString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error sending event: {}. Exception: {}", event.getText(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is the json this code is sending:

```
{"type":"message","channel":"D4CJ8B337","text":"New book!","attachments":[{"fallback":"Something went wrong","color":"#3AA3E3","title":"Do you want to buy this book?","actions":[{"name":"Buy","value":"Yes","text":"Buy","type":"button"},{"name":"No","value":"No","text":"No","type":"button"}],"attachment_type":"default","callback_id":"Djisda"}]}
```

But, as I said, only the text field, "New book!", is being picked up and being shown in the chat. The whole message seems to be valid when I tested it using the Slack Message Builder.
I guess that's it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The RTM API does not accept attachments in messages.

From the Slack docs (https://api.slack.com/rtm):

> > > The RTM API only supports posting simple messages formatted using our default message formatting mode. It does not support attachments or other message formatting modes.

To send attachments, you need to use the chat.postMessage method https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage